# redux-form wizard with submit validation

Tags: redux-form

I have a number of steps in a redux-form wizard.

How the steps validate is through [submit validation](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/submitvalidation/)  (which is where the main problem lies i think)

When I validate on submit on Step1, the submitSecceeded flag is set to true :

```
class Step1 extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        this.props.submitSucceeded //when submit succeeds
    }

}
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'wizard',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
})(Step2);
```

However when I step into Step2 then the submitSecceeded flag is also set to true.

```
class Step2 extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        this.props.submitSucceeded //also true!
    }

}
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'wizard',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
})(Step2);
```

I am guessing redux form is treating the whole wizard as one form. So if the first passes, then it is true for all the other forms.

My question is, does the wizard allow each page to be treated like an individual form?

Comment: Just a guess, I think you are using multiple forms. Can you try to reproduce in stackblitz?

Comment: I think if you want to have individual forms, you don't need the wizard anymore. Just have to keep the states in different places. I understood that you want to keep all the information on the same redux-form state and have all the form flags reseted.  I don't know a way to that on redux-form.